# Remove dynamic user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, webusercontrol

I have a webpage that dynamically loads a user control. Each user control can recursively load the same control within itself. Each control has a delete button. The problem I am having is when the user clicks on the delete button, I need to remove the control that the delete button is contained in.

The page control collection can look like the following:

```
Page
    Group 1
         Category Control
         Category Control
              Category Control
         Category Control
              Category Control
                   Category Control
```

How do I remove a newly created Category Control. I have tried this.Dispose but it does not work.

On the main page that loads the user controls dynamically on adding I have:

```
protected void cmdsubmitsofficecat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int retvalue = 0;
    SQLConnectivity db = new SQLConnectivity();
    SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[8];
    List<group.category> flist = new List<group.category>();
    param[0] = db.MakeInputParameter("@group_id", 1);
    param[1] = db.MakeInputParameter("@parent_id", DBNull.Value);
    param[2] = db.MakeInputParameter("@category_name", this.txtofficecat.Text.Trim());
    param[3] = db.MakeInputParameter("@description", this.txtofficecat.Text.Trim());
    param[4] = db.MakeInputParameter("@organization_id", 1);
    param[5] = db.MakeInputParameter("@created_by", 1);
    param[6] = db.MakeInputParameter("@is_active", 1);
    param[7] = db.MakeOutputIntegerParameter("@category_id");
    db.RunNonQueryProcedure("PerformanceCategorySave", param, ref retvalue);

    if (retvalue != 0)
    {
        group.category item = new group.category();
        item.catid = retvalue;
        item.catname = this.txtofficecat.Text.Trim();
        item.desc = this.txtofficecat.Text.Trim();
        item.isactive = true;
        item.parid = 0;

        catctl ctl = (catctl)Page.LoadControl("~/catctl.ascx");
        ctl.groupid = 1;
        ctl.organizationid = 1;
        ctl.categoryid = item.catid;
        ctl.categoryname = item.catname;
        ctl.parentid = item.parid;
        ctl.ctltype = 1;
        ctl.clist = item.categories;
        ctl.plist = item.points;
        this.officephld.Controls.Add(ctl);
        this.switch_officefields(false, 1);
    }
}
```

On the web user control I have a Page_Load method as:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label ctname = (Label)this.FindControl("ctl0_catname");
    this.catname.Text = categoryname;
    this.cmdaddcat.Attributes.Add("catid", categoryid.ToString());
    this.cmddeletecat.ID = "cmddeletecat" + categoryid.ToString();
    this.cmddeletecat.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(this.cmddeletecat_Click);
    if ( clist != null && clist.Count > 0 )
    {
        int i = 0;
        this.cmddeletecat.Visible = false;
        foreach ( group.category item in clist )
        {
            catctl ctl = (catctl)Page.LoadControl("~/catctl.ascx");
            ctl.categoryid = item.catid;
            ctl.categoryname = item.catname;
            ctl.organizationid = organizationid;
            ctl.groupid = groupid;
            ctl.parentid = item.parid;
            ctl.clist = item.categories;
            ctl.plist = item.points;
            ctl.ctltype = ctltype;
            this.newphld.Controls.Add(ctl);
        }
    }
    if ( plist != null && plist.Count > 0 )
    {
        this.rptPts.Visible = true;
        this.rptPts.DataSource = plist;
        this.rptPts.DataBind();
        this.cmddeletecat.Visible = false;
    }
    this.Switch_Usability();
}
```

and a delete method as:

```
protected void cmddeletecat_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    List<group.category> flist = new List<group.category>();
    SQLConnectivity db = new SQLConnectivity();
    SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[1];
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataTable sdt = new DataTable();
    group parent = new group();

    param[0] = db.MakeInputParameter("@category_id", categoryid);
    db.RunNonQueryProcedure("PerformanceCategoryDelete", param);

    if ( Page != null )
    {
        PlaceHolder ctl = (PlaceHolder)Page.FindControl("officephld");
        if ( ctl != null )
        { ctl.Controls.Remove(this); }
    }
}
```

Comment: isn't this ctl.Controls.Remove(this); working? between you this also a try in cmddeletecat_Click -> this.NamingContainer.Controls.Remove(this);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `newlyCreatedControl.Parent.Controls.Remove(newlyCreatedControl)` method to remove this newlyCreatedControl.

Comment: Where do I find this newlyCreatedControl property?

Comment: newlyCreatedControl is the id of newly added category.. it could be anything

Comment: oh so in C# ASP.NET the newlyCreatedControl would be "this"

Comment: One problem, if the newly created control is directly under the Group 1 heading, the newly created control is in a placeholder under the Group 1 heading, the Parent is being returned as null

Comment: hmm it depends, normally this refers to page itself, but tell me currently how are u referring your category control? Don't you have any id for the category control?

Comment: if the parent is null then you could use Page.Control.Remove(categoryCtrl)

Comment: actually, I dont set the control id. There is a lot of code, would it be easier for me to show you the code behind, and if so how should I go about doing to

Comment: yep edit your question to add some relevant code, it sure will help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3338/discussion-between-waqas-and-mattgcon)

Answer (score 0):

If the delete button is directly inside the control, "this" will refer to the control and you can use the parent to get the controls container.

```
 this.Parent.Controls.Remove(this)
```

If the delete button is inside of a placeholder or another container control inside of the control, you will have to use the Parent twice:

```
 this.Parent.Parent.Controls.Remove(this)
```

If you place this code in the delete click event and hover over the "this" keyword, Intellisense should show you that this refers to your control class.

For example, my dynamic controls have a placeholder where I inject a toolbar control. so to get to the actual module I have to use Parent.Parent ( see the image below, it shows the Intellisense when I hover over this).  "this" refers to the control (in my case the toolbar), the first parent is the Placeholder where the toolbar is inserted and the second parent is the actual module that I am adding to the page Dynamically.   [image: Intellisense]

If I were to call parent a third time it would step up to the container that contains the dynamic control.